# Transiciones de varias vistas android

Tags: java, android

por favor necesito ayuda con las transiciones.en mi `activity_main2.xml` tengo dos vistas una es un `ImageView`  y otro un `FloatingActionButton` lo que quiero es que cuando entre a la actividad 2 desde mi actividad 1 lo haga con animación pero separados osea el `ImageView` que entre con `start` y el `FloatingActionButton` que entre con Top así por separado tengo esta `trasition` en mi `res` y aun así me desplaza toda junta.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">
    <slide android:slideEdge="start">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@id/imagenPortada" />
        </targets>
    </slide>
    <slide android:slideEdge="top">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@id/fab" />
        </targets>
    </slide>
</transitionSet>
```

Y este es mi style donde defino y activo mis transiciones

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#E21E63</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#C2145B</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/transition</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/etransition</item>
</style>
```

Es mas o menos asi lo que quiero conseguir pero en este caso solo con el floatingButton y la portda 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no agregar una imagen de que deseas, lo que tratas de hacer en una actividad que contiene un ImageView y FloatingActionButton lo podrías lograr con un ObjectAnimator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando un **[TransitionManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html)**, para poder mover los elementos por separado, lo que estas usando es para animar dos layouts!

En este caso cuando inicia la "actividad 2" podrías usar simplemente **[ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)** para controlar la traslación de los elementos, por ejemplo si deseas una animación de tu imagen de arriba hacia abajo puede realizarlo con:

```
ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagenPortada, "x", 0f);
ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagenPortada, "y", 1000f);
AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
animSetXY.start();
```

más información **[Animando Vistas (inglés)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views)**

Comment: Perdona pero ya puse la imagen es como quisiera que apareciera al entrar a mi actividad en especial con el FloatingButton y la imagen..Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Hola Elenasys si se puede mover ..pero no hay una forma para que se mueva a su posición original por que me la mueva y se detiene en otra dirección.